# How can I put text files on a provisioned iOS device?

Tags: ios, xcode, io

My program reads and writes text files, but for now it just has a dummy data generator that creates an uninteresting set of data. For the demo I soon need to do, I'd like to display some more interesting data. Can I write text files on my Mac and put them on the device somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Data.txt` to the resources folder and do something like this:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" 
                                                     ofType:@"txt"];
if (filePath != nil) {
  theContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                             error:NULL];

}
```